# Git- create a patch between most recent commit and original commit

Tags: git

I'm preparing to submit my first patch to an open source project. Here's how the process went:

1. Forked project
2. Created initial revision
3. Developer asked me to revise
4. Revised
5. Accepted and ready to go.

However, when I run `git format-patch HEAD^`, I get a diff between my two commits, which obviously doesn't work. Basically, how do I merge the two most recent commits with the project when it was forked, or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [range](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_ranges)

> #### The …​ (three-dot) Symmetric Difference Notation
>
> A similar notation `r1...r2` is called symmetric difference of `r1` and `r2` and is defined as `r1 r2 --not $(git merge-base --all r1 r2)`. It is the set of commits that are reachable from either one of `r1` (left side) or `r2` (right side) but not from both.

So in this case it would be:

```
git format-patch ...master
```